# Can't retrieve crawling errors using Python client

Tags: google-api-client, google-api-python-client, google-search-console

A while ago (around 3 months) I used gsc api to retrieve crawl errors, but it does not work right now. Here is the code:

```
# oauth2flow <--- function implementing authorization
service = oauth2flow(name='webmasters', fname='path_to_client_secret', scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters', version='v3')

self.service.urlcrawlerrorssamples().list(
    siteUrl=siteUrl,
    category=category,
    platform=platform
).execute()
```

The problem is that `urlcrawlerrorsamples` is not recognized (`AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'urlcrawlerrorssamples'`). All other things like `seachanalytics`, `sites` work just fine. I have problem only with crawling errors.

Here is my package list:

```
google-api-core==1.11.1
google-api-python-client==1.7.9
google-auth==1.6.3
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
google-auth-oauthlib==0.2.0
google-cloud-core==1.0.1
google-cloud-storage==1.16.1
google-resumable-media==0.3.2
```